# Add OP-TEE to Yocto

Tags: yocto, op-tee

I am attempting to build a Yocto image incorporating OP-TEE.  I'm used to the output from OP-TEE's build repo (bl1.bin etc) and I can't get the Yocto system to do the same.  Also no `/dev/tee` devices exist (so maybe the kernel isn't configured).  Although xtest and optee-examples have been installed.  I am attempting to first build it against QEMU ARMv8.

Here is my config so far:

local.conf

```
MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-linaro-aarch64"

IMAGES_CLASSES = "image_types_bios image_types_uefi" 

DISTRO ?= "poky"

PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"

EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"

PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"

BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"

CONF_VERSION = "1"

OPTEEOUTPUTMACHINE = "vexpress"
OPTEEMACHINE = "vexpress-qemu_armv8a"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "optee-client optee-examples optee-os optee-test python-pycrypto"
INSANE_SKIP_optee-examples = "ldflags"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = "optee"
```

bblayers.conf

```
BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/poky/meta \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/poky/meta-poky \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/meta-linaro/meta-optee \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/meta-linaro/meta-linaro \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /mnt/raid/yocto_stuff/arm64/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  "
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you also share the dmesg output (if any) from Linux about optee? It is possible that your Linux image does not have the TEE driver or that the device tree entry is missing (https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/firmware/linaro,optee-tz.txt)